# "pass" statement in datetime not working

Tags: python, datetime

I am creating a schedule planner in python.There is a part in my code where I have to wait till the time is met so I added a while loop like this:-

```
import datetime
for i in [0,1,2]:
    print i
        while datetime.datetime.now().time().hour == 22 and datetime.datetime.now().time().minute != i:
            pass
        print i
```

and when the first specified minute is met it prints all the 0,1 and 2.
Can anyone please help me.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `pass` does nothing. What did you expect it to do here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I expected it to do nothing but instead when the minute 0 is met it is supposed to print 0 not 0,1,2

Comment: Why would `i` be changed at all? The `while` loop continues until your computer time matches the given minute, so at `i = 0`, the time must be 22:00 for the loop to end. `i` itself *doesn't change*.

Comment: Ah, you are probably expecting *pauses* between the numbers?

Comment: @MartijnPieters  It should change after it matches the given minute to 1 according to for loop

Comment: Writing to the terminal is *buffered*, so you need to flush to update the screen. What terminal or console is this in?

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you vote it up please.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am using pycharm on windows.It runs using python.exe

Comment: Please don't demand how people vote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry,I thought you mistakenly voted down thinking different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expected there to be *pauses* between the numbers, you need to *flush your output*. Writing to your terminal is *buffered*, writing a single integer is not enough:

```
import sys

# ...
print i
sys.stdout.flush()  # force a buffer flush
```